# Chaning returned pointer after it's been returned in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm returning an void* pointer to a chunk in memory in this function:

memory.cpp:

```
int mem[1000];
int* pointers[100];
int start_index = 100;

void* allocate(int size) {
    pointers[0] = &mem[start_index];
    return (void *) pointers[0];
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int* arr = (int*) allocate(50); // allocate array of size 50 starting at mem[100]
arr[0] = 62;                    // changes mem[100] to 62
```

Now say I wanna make the user of this function use different location of mem array, without the user of allocate function being notified (assuming it'd be no problem we lose the data).

Can't I do this?

memory.cpp:

```
pointers[0] = &mem[200];
```

After this line is executed in memory.cpp, I want `arr[0]` point to `mem[200]`.
Is that possible without changing the prototype of allocate function?

Thanks

Comment: Right, fixed it in question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. You would need to return a pointer-to-a-pointer (`void**`) and make it absolutely clear to clients of the `allocate` function that they are not allowed to create aliases to the memory. Anyways, this is a *very* bad idea, you'll run into problems left and right (e.g. what if your client uses in-place `new` to allocate a non-POD object in that memory?)

Comment: Ah huh, thanks. That was the answer I was looking for. I'm not allowed to change the prototype of the allocate function though, otherwise `void**` would be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change a pointer to point at something else anytime.

However, this will only change the pointer you assign to, not other places using the old pointer. So if some code saves the returned value from your `allocate` function, and you later change `pointers[0]` to point to something else, the old saved pointer will not change.

Comment: Right, so there is no way to change the memory `arr` is pointing to, inside memory.cpp?

Comment: @user2256172 No there isn't.